# Text marks in a nested layered chart built in Vega-Lite

Tags: powerbi, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I am attempting to add **total** text marks to my nested layered chart. It works fine with text marks added to one of the bar marks:

[image]

[text marks added to 1 bar mark - VL editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMoi0AdiUAxGrIAEATThIATmgBMABg8BmG3ZIslA0OvYAsnL09gBy7qgAjAGyQSFhkbL0aCAA8lCYiiAA0gAKAJKxSAhw2QCignBQ9gBmrmwI9gBKcLJwAO5ITA0GSqUVJmyuBageSgCqEEhkcPYAwo6eCZQAbAAc84vL9iUbM76UACyzIAAqbsvTHlu7AJxKJW3KDPnsDutoFwsewSL2270+30wv2OpzECQuYj8vgAvgpTOZUFYQLYHM43J4fP5sYFgqFBBEojBYvEksSUqT0pTsnkCqNypVqnUGk1Wu1YnJ+N1egMhvpCmN7BMpmhaQslit-okvFsvFi5UcTmgxBJ4Uo7q4HlqtmIiR82F8fnI1qdAcDQeDzZDoZrUHCEUjUejMDVMcknC54t4-MlUmSKZkqXFPCGGeSMll0DE2MRxeyYlUfSB6o0Wm0OkL+oNhqnxpNHgd5daCZRdSB1SsXR4LJQxFj9YaZhILFizRaoVbFWIriamw6+87YV4LhcXr4vJ6QGZvZY-XjA4SY2k45TqdG6aHGRHskmU2yKunOehszy8-zZIKeoXRSNiuypdNZYcFaddh4a9d6xhNBtmbYNbnuOBpm2P9dlNCFLT+WFh18UcQF7J0rRdMQpxnOcFyXH0sRxf18RmDd91jcNoijVAiRxA9tyPdAABFGhLDlM2vXM+QLEVizPSUyz3QDFQRGsxArDUbQuShfDBcCDUggEtgRMcMMQgFtgSPxdi8NSEKA2iLAubZtinfCMSIuwSPXMD6Mo+NI3iOiSS3KiYGyVioHYi9OO5biOiTe9eKLMUBPfGVJO-GUvF2FtP0rF1Zx2Wl2yU1BdmbC59jQ+D+w01ATO03xdP0-LDN8YzTPMtFF0s1cAwJOzXLDRzd0KzdWqZdAACkgh8jMuRzXl80fPiwtfUtpRmKKq1ol5KFnWasLiok0umIdLhy9CDMVXwQVVJbcsdAzG1nTKPDECzl19OkbKalz6TctqaIuTrDwTEA+vkATfKGm8+SCh9hVCl8JQixJZsVF5mxK5bTgSRHKC8N4FI7BIvHOXZaR28q9oOiwjtxidPHOixLuuwiGtIoNHoY9z2okijnu67E4CYAbLyzfyRq6MbQfYiGAK-Ob9prVHAJdC4VXk9a0BK2Sezy6E9qBWDATKknaISCwTReedaoIlc7rXB73sY6j4iZ+yWaYtmOd+warx528gZC59BaEyG6xFxUMfOE14ZlBIu1SiCP1ims4JOvHTkqvZfA147x0wuOdb1g2vSpk3GrI5qnq6iN2vkm3C8+8J8UdrmuN593+MmwTpuFytFRAQpJdODwZN8Nbw88P8LGjlOCrbzXU803YzMTynjeI0287phydxokuWo+jz0Ar9wq784bXYFOuJvBr2EqOVv25FpKFrhtH0peGClZjlXTlH5P1MMkzJ8xi4Z9uufc9pubBmNErIF3XtkAAgjgbeDc-rOz3jxfmHtwpe2bmfF+F9EqdzirsN6t9HjbEWkzYmA4MFjwcGdBIplda-1AfdBeQCXrxFAfTRykDoGc13gDQKB8kH12PtNU+0V0CYKkjKMQC0QJ6j7okGclAnjkLmq-EhFDO4vCoSBK6ht6o5xpuRUu692o5QMRbDeIAK4AE9OH-QCneYGT5+FvhPlDMhPssEyjkR4VGctEi+AWnCRR59FGNguHJBIulaHU1sovW2ls0DGLXqY7IljrHwO4XzEGyCG5CxcdkURDZO5-jEDlHxTwayBNcSowyXcwkRO0TdOh89AHMzLk5NAqMTHuWyD1BgP1YFO25gg0amTHFTXLG49BeSg6JEIftaRikPwSC7hUqZb9TpxznBYHwHhIm6OiYw5e8QOmJK6b1XpqTBnpLdnwo+TjBG5JEdMxGMlA74Jis2HwKzHlrPKi6Huqptm7P-no-OrDDkxQOXbHpggLk133sFG5YM7kfgea-DuMo5LIxKTI7SzYdZfOUcrceMwLCwQSD3IF1kmn6JOUwiFLTwFnJhTvGxtdEWeybqi-JhkdaUFJfM9GhCtIEsKFUxspL9oUvqdnYF+yGWmPaojSFn0IEMDILCl2iCRm3LGcJX2rj0UzBUgK9K3gRXBLjtlOElVKW4gATSsBCqaJKvlackAqr1UsrSbY652qkW6u9iJA1l8EYeDioiE1H5vDlJ+c-VZYrLW7GtRYW19DmmdLpYka4GbWYmDgDgDVQyMkOJ1Y3cZQbVmGpDpQSekaPE1uuFUoJsbiXun1rFVN1LQVLyLs67NtLc35sLVc3hfqOUoomcItFIb2kLRRnW1A98djmpbaovJyIAC6qIQCYFcEECAzRJgICMKAKAOgoAMEEGoTMAByJtDBXCuB6Jgew1hHA3sKEgAw6Am2OHsAAGXID0ZQIAFxnsEBeq9N0QB3qJRQ1w7BXCvvfZ+79q6YQAaA7IEDYHz2XuvdkG915d00BCJgCx9h1ofqUF+7I61MPLGw6B2q4HIMEfQKoTADAECGBvRKXyN6N32AANT2BvTCajIBaPoFWNesgkwLGalwxB-D0HOPcd4-xjMgmRNietJJ6TIBZPenk64Cx-xN1KHgDQMgWB5ZeD0iAPoNBlAJjMo5qAchmg2bQKABojGQOaBAJMGgz7shMDYNgdohRPO6AQLIb91wr0WLYAwaYoAItRePUF1IMBJjZAQC55QDRQPIjK0oZLcB4jGBAJV6rfmkAWKqyekAKRq7chI2Rij-wlDIFcAAa18zuixOBMxMEriAAAHjkZozQIDpUcxAGgAAvH0GMlCYDYGwQQUIC2oF3XobdPRPPKDsOqoLk2hvebgIIQLrq6UbZG5mSYp2UjMqk5Nmg36GtMBuxA2QZASuoHnNuqxQXru3eyBWx7o3sgAEcGBBChOoKEpBCjI6B5czrdAKNlEyD0Jb5H7AAAp+sAHUqQEHsJt+DT85AAEpmMgFi-l8HoXIcybkwpnrw3YfoFkO0QI73oA6B9KAZQ7QkB2CMJc2xh8IBASUHCwGo6S0K81ErzVwy1dVk10W31Ov-gbqUHugHPpDAgAAMTTlBAAIVWIUS3YgIGrF2NYCBju-EQMTrbx3FxVjMVBBcEAW6KtYcC6ADHmZStKBe81tnN3AsW+M+QbnGxjfBdcMoePFuv1QGA2dkPZWFxta4djongEbiRbCMxNQSAAODBuy+Prg2gvkb5zuuAk3WRSeEGQeQ6AEO2Z7+N+bwhejZHH3AfgmXNvHqUMoS7iQsSHsyGYVb7SjvBHNIXi7V32d3Zzb2mB7fntZ6F0zsHoAlhkCfRQaDEBuOFAh3d6HvPMwI6R3QNQNA0fbu9N3kNjfnfuxiAI-vPiAC-lDvqujk9vDojpkN-qjjUEoIeq4MgNMIUMXqHqAKXv9OXhRhriAC3kNqfuFhNtNrNvNtMPwC6kthvkqBtltjtjQHtgdnAFvidrvqAEvqAFAegEfnEjDmfq9joJ+p9t9rVo3oIP9oDj6CDkoFfpAQftAe4sIfAV-ijr-igR9l9mgLIJeoINuizvEHwSoZziZgpkQWQfzoLm9oUCLkDuLpLtLqgBbsrtruNOrhsHriOgin6orrLmygETzh4XYvLlWBnqbssDLtbjONsPbo7s7q7u7p7i8N7hcL7koNbgHkHkXmHgFqQXQJjjHpntnqYcoYnjLinqZopunrHlnjnlJtAAXgDkXuVrgQMjcBAp0AAOK1A3CFAkFt5wHoDjYwKUFzbpR0ErZrYebbas5W7WDWCrCrAObo7MG7ZoDsGcE75tF74J4c73bgrqHoAvYX40YSFDZXq-YyEA5A4KEgBKHAF8AP5P6oHmFvKnEgCf6IFaFo6XF6GoAGGCBGEfGgn75VHoD0aAaFFKCOFi4gDRHm5LErFrFeD5G1bh5FGYAlHF6WZIn6DbZo5BYIlDZg5gEwBuBwA4aAmSEUl2DZ6jbYZhbF61R1YtZ4E-pwa67EFuCt6R6jG1Z2A6GbbbZbH7auCHZKDHZ7HnY8GQlHGCFtLfHnH2Gg6Kl3a-qwEd6-HI4-4Ak7rFGZhVLE406M7boQC7psD9aIn8HobrAMbAYOHgaInIky5DBIBQCDah5YmFFt7GnrpsmdFcwJpDH8mkFClT4bHimsHbFSkcEynb6vbylTaanZDKm7iqnn7qmKFAFkC36vGZjgHP6fFhnfF6lIHaHiFAkglglgHWm2npncl06qJOlMbwmulDbuluGEkga+n+bOkBm4nR74lRFEmCAkmgBklBYMksnMnZ6ZAOGNmZiMn5rAasllZbpAA)

But as soon as I add for the rest, the second Y-Axis is thrown off:

[image]

[text marks added to all marks - VL editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAMoi0AdiUAxGrIAEATThIATmgBMABg8BmG3ZIslA0OvYAsnL09gBy7qgAjAGyQSFhkbL0aCAA8lCYiiAA0gAKAJKxSAhw2QCignBQ9gBmrmwI9gBKcLJwAO5ITA0GSqUVJmyuBageSgCqEEhkcPYAwo6eCZQAbAAc84vL9iUbM76UACyzIAAqbsvTHlu7AJxKJW3KDPnsDutoFwsewSL2270+30wv2OpzECQuYj8vgAvgpTOZUFYQLYHM43J4fP5sYFgqFBBEojBYvEksSUqT0pTsnkCqNypVqnUGk1Wu1YnJ+N1egMhvpCmN7BMpmhaQslit-okvFsvFi5UcTmgxBJ4Uo7q4HlqtmIiR82F8fnI1qdAcDQeDzZDoZrUHCEUjUejMDVMcknC54t4-MlUmSKZkqXFPCGGeSMll0DE2MRxeyYlUfSB6o0Wm0OkL+oNhqnxpNHgd5daCZRdSB1SsXR4LJQxFj9YaZhILFizRaoVbFWIriamw6+87YV4LhcXr4vJ6QGZvZY-XjA4SY2k45TqdG6aHGRHskmU2yKunOehszy8-zZIKeoXRSNiuypdNZYcFaddh4a9d6xhNBtmbYNbnuOBpm2P9dlNCFLT+WFh18UcQF7J0rRdMQpxnOcFyXH0sRxf18RmDd91jcNoijVAiRxA9tyPdAABFGhLDlM2vXM+QLEVizPSUyz3QDFQRGsxArDUbQuShfDBcCDUggEtgRMcMMQgFtgSPxdi8NSEKA2iLAubZtinfCMSIuwSPXMD6Mo+NI3iOiSS3KiYGyVioHYi9OO5biOiTe9eKLMUBPfGVJO-GUvF2FtP0rF1Zx2Wl2yU1BdmbC59jQ+D+w01ATO03xdP0-LDN8YzTPMtFF0s1cAwJOzXLDRzd0KzdWqZdAACkgh8jMuRzXl80fPiwtfUtpRmKKq1ol5KFnWasLiok0umIdLhy9CDMVXwQVVJbcsdAzG1nTKPDECzl19OkbKalz6TctqaIuTrDwTEA+vkATfKGm8+SCh9hVCl8JQixJZsVF5mxK5bTgSRHKC8N4FI7BIvHOXZaR28q9oOiwjtxidPHOixLuuwiGtIoNHoY9z2okijnu67E4CYAbLyzfyRq6MbQfYiGAK-Ob9prVHAJdC4VXk9a0BK2Sezy6E9qBWDATKknaISCwTReedaoIlc7rXB73sY6j4iZ+yWaYtmOd+warx528gZC59BaEyG6xFxUMfOE14ZlBIu1SiCP1ims4JOvHTkqvZfA147x0wuOdb1g2vSpk3GrI5qnq6iN2vkm3C8+8J8UdrmuN593+MmwTpuFytFRAQpJdODwZN8Nbw88P8LGjlOCrbzXU803YzMTynjeI0287phydxokuWo+jz0Ar9wq784bXYFOuJvBr2EqOVv25FpKFrhtH0peGClZjlXTlH5P1MMkzJ8xi4Z9uufc9pubBmNErIF3XtkAAgjgbeDc-rOz3jxfmHtwpe2bmfF+F9EqdzirsN6t9HjbEWkzYmA4MFjwcGdBIplda-1AfdBeQCXrxFAfTRykDoGc13gDQKB8kH12PtNU+0V0CYKkjKMQC0QJ6j7okGclAnjkLmq-EhFDO4vCoSBK6ht6o5xpuRUu692o5QMRbDeIAK4AE9OH-QCneYGT5+FvhPlDMhPssEyjkR4VGctEi+AWnCRR59FGNguHJBIulaHU1sovW2ls0DGLXqY7IljrHwO4XzEGyCG5CxcdkURDZO5-jEDlHxTwayBNcSowyXcwkRO0TdOh89AHMzLk5NAqMTHuWyD1BgP1YFO25gg0amTHFTXLG49BeSg6JEIftaRikPwSC7hUqZb9TpxznBYHwHhIm6OiYw5e8QOmJK6b1XpqTBnpLdnwo+TjBG5JEdMxGMlA74Jis2HwKzHlrPKi6Huqptm7P-no-OrDDkxQOXbHpggLk133sFG5YM7kfgea-DuMo5LIxKTI7SzYdZfOUcrceMwLCwQSD3IF1kmn6JOUwiFLTwFnJhTvGxtdEWeybqi-JhkdaUFJfM9GhCtIEsKFUxspL9oUvqdnYF+yGWmPaojSFn0IEMDILCl2iCRm3LGcJX2rj0UzBUgK9K3gRXBLjtlOElVKW4gATSsBCqaJKvlackAqr1UsrSbY652qkW6u9iJA1l8EYeDioiE1H5vDlJ+c-VZYrLW7GtRYW19DmmdLpYka4GbWYmDgDgDVQyMkOJ1Y3cZQbVmGpDpQSekaPE1uuFUoJsbiXun1rFVN1LQVLyLs67NtLc35sLVc3hfqOUoomcItFIb2kLRRnW1A98djmpbaovJyIAC6qIQCYFcEECAzRJgICMKAKAOgoAMEEGoTMAByJtDBXCuB6Jgew1hHA3sKEgAw6Am2OHsAAGXID0ZQIAFxnsEBeq9N0QB3qJRQ1w7BXCvvfZ+79q6YQAaA7IEDYHz2XuvdkG915d00BCJgCx9h1ofqUF+7I61MPLGw6B2q4HIMEfQKoTADAECGBvRKXyN6N32AANT2BvTCajIBaPoFWNesgkwLGalwxB-D0HOPcd4-xjMgmRNietJJ6TIBZPenk64Cx-xN1KHgDQMgWB5ZeD0iAPoNBlAJjMo5qAchmg2bQKABojGQOaBAJMGgz7shMDYNgdohRPO6AQLIb91wr0WLYAwaYoAItRePUF1IMBJjZAQC55QDRQPIjK0oZLcB4jGBAJV6rfmkAWKqyekAKRq7chI2Rij-wlDIFcAAa18zuixOBMxMEriAAAHjkZozQIDpUcxAGgAAvH0GMlCYDYGwQQUIC2oF3XobdPRPPKDsOqoLk2hvebgIIQLrq6UbZG5mSYp2UjMqk5Nmg36GtMBuxA2QZASuoHnNuqxQXru3eyBWx7o3sgAEcGBBChOoKEpBCjI6B5czrdAKNlEyD0Jb5H7AAAp+sAHUqQEHsJt+DT85AAEpmMgFi-l8HoXIcybkwpnrw3YfoFkO0QI73oA6B9KAZQ7QkB2CMJc2xh8IBASUHCwGo6S0K81ErzVwy1dVk10W31Ov-gbqUHugHPpDAgAAMTTlBAAIVWIUS3YgIGrF2NYCBju-EQMTrbx3FxVjMVBBcEAW6KtYcC6ADHmZStKBe81tnN3AsW+M+QbnGxjfBdcMoePFuv1QGA2dkPZWFxta4djongEbiRbCMxNQSAAODBuy+Prg2gvkb5zuuAk3WRSeEGQeQ6AEO2Z7+N+bwhejZHH3AfgmXNvHqUMoS7iQsSHsyGYVb7SjvBHNIXi7V32d3Zzb2mB7fntZ6F0zsHoAlhkCfRQaDEBuOFAh3d6HvPMwI6R3QNQNA0fbu9N3kNjfnfuxiAI-vPiAC-lDvqujk9vDojpkN-qjjUEoIeq4MgNMIUMXqHg1k1vVq1gMsRghl1oriAC3kNqfuFhNtNrNvNtMPwC6kthvkqBtltjtjQHtgdnAFvidrvqAEvqAFAegEfnEjDmfq9joJ+p9t9rVo3oIP9oDj6CDkoFfpAQftAe4mIfAV-ijr-igR9l9mgLIJeoINuizvEIIeoZziZgphru-tkALoVm9oUCLkDuLpLtLqgBbsrtruNOrhsHriOgin6qQT4cWn4brrLrzAbhEUbibkEMsDLtbjONsPbo7s7q7u7p7i8N7hcL7koNbgHkHkXmHgFhQXQJjjHpntnhYWoYnjLinqZopunrHlnjnlJtAAXgDkXuVqAKXv9OXhRh3JRtXuSLXuoA3r9oIM3m4K3pHnAegAAT3joDZgPiAEPnZkoKPjdnYJmFPjPpFnPoUIvmgI5qvpgOvj6C8DwTvt0XvgnhzvduCloegC9hfqDkAWQLfnwA-k-qgVYZOqQZQegJ-ogboX-htl3ullJl8SAb8RAUIYCXYcCSAKCcjj-mjqgUemoNkEoNgQuHVi1v0egDcBAp0AAOK1A3CFDkFt4LEgDjYwI0FzbpSMErZrYebbas5W7WDWCrCrAObo5sG7ZoBcE3Gvbnb8H771HCEDrH6wEd5vHOE0bSFDZXpTEKFA7KEgCqHAE-GZjgHP4AlywvGokIHonIFSGGGoDGGCCmH-F2nSmPH0aAZlFKCuFi7rEJHm48l8kCleAlG1bh7lGYCVHF4l4DKkkUlUmTFN40mzEUH0lLGfp95rEbEj5fo7ET7oD7Gz7RYL5L5gTnGXGb5KDHa3GSlTZOmH5ymiH2GvHn7OEfE5awn6nZCGn-EylvKmlolIF6FM7JktnfH34Gl-F1HOl9w9nml9mYmQHYmYF4llZboZ5PoyCCBo5BYelDZg5gEwBuBwA4YqnWmgA7l2DZ6jbYZhbF61SEleG4E559EDK-rxkDaJkd5T5CnbYin7auCHZlnb4SlDYCHjk1mOrAIn70lKmSHNmWFdnPlTk6EYn6FR7ZBVLE406M7boQC7psD9aemIm-oMbAYuHgaemm6JFeEMlXpQCDah5BllFt4VHR7hm1TEnobrD2DjH17-pyEzGvl0kd7Jk0apnZDpmFDbEfk5m7EHFZbHFL7rZzmZBajil8FVkPGgVgrymmlQUwowUwnDmgEdkgWoVwaREom9ngk1D-5QmfEGXwlGlwWmU87mXTmWXP7zm4mlaboEmNYPkEFcwJovlzH1m1a7GfnsGcG-ncH-m8F3FSnqXZAiFtLaWNnQUqG2VwmjkIkAmBUIVglIVWnfq2n2lgE4V4XVkmV06qJEVMbumkVDbkU+lPogZ0X+bEWMWhnMXXmPkBWmUnCcV16xnTFBVvmZhCW96rGiU2abEMmZmSWhW9AyVHEFmnFYlKWugqVxVqWwWPFJW7gpUSG6XpVDmZXtljkEV9UBEhUWUFXWWAEnVtnoBGUXVVVAn0k3WWlYnoE4noCLneUrn6DbYbmgBblBanmXkXnZ5KXullWZhnn5rAZXlLnIhAA)

Is this happening because I am applying aggregations in the creation of the text marks? How can I overcome this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think things are getting confusing with so many nested layers. Try reusing the ones you already have like this:

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 21.68,
        "Usage PY": 23.42,
        "Target": 21.89,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 1,
        "Financial Month": "Oct",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 101.07,
        "Usage PY": 55.14,
        "Target": 51.53,
        "Production CY": 4768196,
        "Production PY": 5145233
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 20.14,
        "Usage PY": 27.57,
        "Target": 25.77,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 2,
        "Financial Month": "Nov",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 82.12,
        "Usage PY": 67.23,
        "Target": 62.83,
        "Production CY": 5425327,
        "Production PY": 5044930
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 45.15,
        "Usage PY": 44.36,
        "Target": 41.45,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 3,
        "Financial Month": "Dec",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 108.51,
        "Usage PY": 93.61,
        "Target": 87.48,
        "Production CY": 4612380,
        "Production PY": 3746604
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 39.93,
        "Usage PY": 58.3,
        "Target": 54.48,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 4,
        "Financial Month": "Jan",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 97.38,
        "Usage PY": 111.09,
        "Target": 103.81,
        "Production CY": 3190793,
        "Production PY": 2938725
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": 31.19,
        "Usage PY": 41.06,
        "Target": 38.37,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 5,
        "Financial Month": "Feb",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": 103.53,
        "Usage PY": 115.71,
        "Target": 108.13,
        "Production CY": 3768347,
        "Production PY": 3175390
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 24.33,
        "Target": 22.73,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 6,
        "Financial Month": "Mar",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.38,
        "Target": 92.87,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4686034
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 28.84,
        "Target": 26.95,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 7,
        "Financial Month": "Apr",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 159.67,
        "Target": 149.21,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2916675
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 149.29,
        "Target": 139.51,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 8,
        "Financial Month": "May",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 22.58,
        "Target": 21.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2436180
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 16.31,
        "Target": 15.24,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 9,
        "Financial Month": "Jun",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 114.53,
        "Target": 107.02,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3307022
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 136.08,
        "Target": 127.17,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 10,
        "Financial Month": "Jul",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 17.78,
        "Target": 16.61,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 2783133
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 21.4,
        "Target": 20,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 11,
        "Financial Month": "Aug",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 128.52,
        "Target": 120.1,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 3485137
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 2,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 15.86,
        "Target": 14.82,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": 4529008
      },
      {
        "Site": 7,
        "Fin Year": 2023,
        "Financial Month Nr": 12,
        "Financial Month": "Sep",
        "KPI Name": "Elec from Non-Renewables",
        "KPI Sort": 1,
        "Usage CY": "",
        "Usage PY": 99.09,
        "Target": 92.6,
        "Production CY": "",
        "Production PY": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "'Production Current FY'", "as": "Production CY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Production Prior FY'", "as": "Production PY Legend"},
    {"calculate": "'Electricity Target'", "as": "Target Legend"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' PY'", "as": "CategoryPY"},
    {"calculate": "datum['KPI Name'] + ' CY'", "as": "CategoryCY"}
  ],
  "height": 300,
  "width": 600,
  "config": {
    "legend": {
      "orient": "bottom",
      "columns": 2,
      "layout": {"bottom": {"anchor": "middle"}}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Electricity CY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": 0, "size": 10, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Electricity Intensity (kWh / ton Production)"
            },
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryCY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Elec from Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Renewables CY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryCY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity PY",
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "xOffset": -11, "size": 10, "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {"field": "Usage PY", "type": "quantitative", "axis": null},
            "color": {
              "field": "CategoryPY",
              "type": "nominal",
              "scale": {
                "domain": [
                  "Elec from Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables PY",
                  "Elec from Renewables CY",
                  "Elec from Non-Renewables CY"
                ],
                "range": ["#4496BC", "#5AC8FA", "#39A34B", "#4CD964"]
              },
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            },
            "order": {"field": ["CategoryPY"], "order": ["ascending"]}
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET",
          "mark": {
            "type": "bar",
            "xOffset": 11,
            "size": 10,
            "color": "#FFCC00",
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "Financial Month Nr",
              "type": "ordinal",
              "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "fill": {
              "field": "Target Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["#FFCC00"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity Usage Total Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 17,
            "fontSize": 9
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ","
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Electricity Usage PY Total Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 0,
            "fontSize": 9
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Usage PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ","
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "TARGET Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 23,
            "fontSize": 9
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Target",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ","
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "shared"}, "axis": {"y": "independent"}}
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "name": "Production CY",
          "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "field": "Production CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "title": "Production (ton)"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production CY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["black"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Production PY",
          "mark": {"type": "line", "tooltip": true},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "stroke": {
              "field": "Production PY Legend",
              "scale": {"range": ["red"]},
              "legend": {"title": ""}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Production CY Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 10,
            "font": 5
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production CY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ","
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "Production PY Data Labels",
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right",
            "baseline": "line-bottom",
            "dx": 0,
            "font": 5
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "Financial Month Nr", "type": "ordinal"},
            "y": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": null
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": "sum",
              "field": "Production PY",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "format": ","
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "resolve": {"scale": {"y": "independent", "stroke": "independent"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you David! Indeed, the nested layering was getting confusing. I attempted to re-using the layers but I see you placed the text marks after each of the bar marks. Perhaps that is where I went wrong, placing the text mark right after its respective bar mark... This is more elegant, and easier to read! Thanks again :)

Comment: FYI, I would normally build stuff like this in Vega as if offers much more flexibility once you get past the simple charts. Take a look at https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase for examples.

Comment: I already have this bookmarked :) But thank you!